# first and last methods : scala, spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Pyspark, we have :
The first() function returns the first element present in the column, **when the ignoreNulls is set to True, it returns the first non-null element.**
The last() function returns the last element present in the column, **when ignoreNulls is set to True, it further returns the last non-null element.**

I would like to know, if we have equivalent methods for scala spark env.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is available in Scala Spark same as PySpark.

```
df.select(functions.first("col1",ignoreNulls = true),
          functions.last("col2",ignoreNulls = true))
  .show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

A quick look at the documentation gives you `first` and `last`: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#first(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column

> `def first(columnName: String): Column`
>
> Aggregate function: returns the first value of a column in a group.
>
> The function by default returns the first values it sees. It will return the first non-null value it sees when ignoreNulls is set to true. If all values are null, then null is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Spark is developed using Scala, so any scala methods you want to use in Spark are available.